# How to retrieve data using primary key (INT) by store Procedure in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've created a store procedure to fetch data. The sql code is below. when i'm using another column(varchar) its working .. but when i'm trying to use by primary key (int) the below code is not working.

```
Create PROCEDURE ABC
(in @ID int) 
as 
Begin 
   SELECT * 
   FROM class
   where id = @ID
END

DECLARE @ID INT;
SET @ID = 26;
CALL ABC(@ID)
```

[This is database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfcXy.png)

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Post error messages/behavour

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as
Begin
   SELECT *
   FROM class
   where id = ID
END

SET @ID = ' at line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots if mistakes here try

```
drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
Create PROCEDURE p
(in inID int) 

Begin 
   SELECT * 
   FROM users
   where id = inID;
END $$

delimiter ;

SET @ID = 1;
CALL p(@ID)
```

Comment: It still shows this !!

Error

Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

    Unrecognized keyword. (near "ON" at position 25)

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

MySQL said: Documentation
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: But whenever i run this query SET @ID = 5;
CALL p(@ID) 
... it doesn't give me any value except that error !!!

Comment: I'm sorry this seems to be purely a phpmyadmin issue, works fine in command line, mysqlworkbench and heidisql, I don't know phpmyadmin and can't help you with that.